# Infovis doesn't layout the graph when used in a Django page

Tags: javascript, python, django, infovis

I'm trying to integrate [an example](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example2.html) of a [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/index.html) graph into my Django application.

For now, I just want the aforementioned samle graph be displayed in my Django page. I created the template given below.

But it doesn't work as intended. The original graph is laid out right after the web page is loaded.

My graph isn't and it's necessary to manually move the nodes to the links between them.

You can see how it works in this [video](http://youtu.be/PjMEXPOscsA).

What should I change in my template and/or scripts and/or CSS files in order for the graph to be laid out immediately after the page is loaded (like in the original example) ?

Here's my Django template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% block prehtml %}
{% endblock %}

<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/graphs.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var labelType, useGradients, nativeTextSupport, animate;

        (function() {
          var ua = navigator.userAgent,
              iStuff = ua.match(/iPhone/i) || ua.match(/iPad/i),
              typeOfCanvas = typeof HTMLCanvasElement,
              nativeCanvasSupport = (typeOfCanvas == 'object' || typeOfCanvas == 'function'),
              textSupport = nativeCanvasSupport 
                && (typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').fillText == 'function');
          //I'm setting this based on the fact that ExCanvas provides text support for IE
          //and that as of today iPhone/iPad current text support is lame
          labelType = (!nativeCanvasSupport || (textSupport && !iStuff))? 'Native' : 'HTML';
          nativeTextSupport = labelType == 'Native';
          useGradients = nativeCanvasSupport;
          animate = !(iStuff || !nativeCanvasSupport);
        })();

        var Log = {
          elem: false,
          write: function(text){
            if (!this.elem) 
              this.elem = document.getElementById('log');
            this.elem.innerHTML = text;
            this.elem.style.left = (500 - this.elem.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
          }
        };


        function init(){
          // init data
          var json = [
              {
                "adjacencies": [
                    "graphnode21", 
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode1",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode0",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode13",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode0",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode14",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode0",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode15",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode0",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode16",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode0",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode17",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode0",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#83548B",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 10
                },
                "id": "graphnode0",
                "name": "graphnode0"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode2",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode4",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode5",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode6",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode7",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode8",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode10",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode11",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode12",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode13",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode14",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode15",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode16",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode17",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#EBB056",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 11
                },
                "id": "graphnode1",
                "name": "graphnode1"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode5",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode2",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode9",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode2",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode18",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode2",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#416D9C",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 7
                },
                "id": "graphnode2",
                "name": "graphnode2"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode5",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode3",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#909291"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode9",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode3",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode10",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode3",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode12",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode3",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#416D9C",
                  "$type": "square",
                  "$dim": 10
                },
                "id": "graphnode3",
                "name": "graphnode3"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#83548B",
                  "$type": "square",
                  "$dim": 11
                },
                "id": "graphnode4",
                "name": "graphnode4"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                  {
                    "nodeTo": "graphnode9",
                    "nodeFrom": "graphnode5",
                    "data": {
                      "$color": "#909291"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#C74243",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 8
                },
                "id": "graphnode5",
                "name": "graphnode5"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode10",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode6",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode11",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode6",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#83548B",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 11
                },
                "id": "graphnode6",
                "name": "graphnode6"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#EBB056",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 12
                },
                "id": "graphnode7",
                "name": "graphnode7"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#C74243",
                  "$type": "star",
                  "$dim": 10
                },
                "id": "graphnode8",
                "name": "graphnode8"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#83548B",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 12
                },
                "id": "graphnode9",
                "name": "graphnode9"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                  {
                    "nodeTo": "graphnode11",
                    "nodeFrom": "graphnode10",
                    "data": {
                      "$color": "#909291"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#70A35E",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 11
                },
                "id": "graphnode10",
                "name": "graphnode10"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#70A35E",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 11
                },
                "id": "graphnode11",
                "name": "graphnode11"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#83548B",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 10
                },
                "id": "graphnode12",
                "name": "graphnode12"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                  {
                    "nodeTo": "graphnode14",
                    "nodeFrom": "graphnode13",
                    "data": {
                      "$color": "#557EAA"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#EBB056",
                  "$type": "star",
                  "$dim": 7
                },
                "id": "graphnode13",
                "name": "graphnode13"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#EBB056",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 12
                },
                "id": "graphnode14",
                "name": "graphnode14"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode16",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode15",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode17",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode15",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#83548B",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 11
                },
                "id": "graphnode15",
                "name": "graphnode15"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                  {
                    "nodeTo": "graphnode17",
                    "nodeFrom": "graphnode16",
                    "data": {
                      "$color": "#557EAA"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#C74243",
                  "$type": "star",
                  "$dim": 7
                },
                "id": "graphnode16",
                "name": "graphnode16"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#416D9C",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 7
                },
                "id": "graphnode17",
                "name": "graphnode17"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [
                    {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode19",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode18",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }, {
                      "nodeTo": "graphnode20",
                      "nodeFrom": "graphnode18",
                      "data": {
                        "$color": "#557EAA"
                      }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#EBB056",
                  "$type": "triangle",
                  "$dim": 9
                },
                "id": "graphnode18",
                "name": "graphnode18"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#70A35E",
                  "$type": "circle",
                  "$dim": 8
                },
                "id": "graphnode19",
                "name": "graphnode19"
              }, {
                "adjacencies": [],
                "data": {
                  "$color": "#C74243",
                  "$type": "star",
                  "$dim": 8
                },
                "id": "graphnode20",
                "name": "graphnode20"
              }
          ];
          // end
          // init ForceDirected
          var fd = new $jit.ForceDirected({
            //id of the visualization container
            injectInto: 'graph',
            //Enable zooming and panning
            //by scrolling and DnD
            Navigation: {
              enable: true,
              //Enable panning events only if we're dragging the empty
              //canvas (and not a node).
              panning: 'avoid nodes',
              zooming: 10 //zoom speed. higher is more sensible
            },
            // Change node and edge styles such as
            // color and width.
            // These properties are also set per node
            // with dollar prefixed data-properties in the
            // JSON structure.
            Node: {
              overridable: true
            },
            Edge: {
              overridable: true,
              color: '#23A4FF',
              lineWidth: 0.4
            },
            //Native canvas text styling
            Label: {
              type: labelType, //Native or HTML
              size: 10,
              style: 'bold'
            },
            //Add Tips
            Tips: {
              enable: true,
              onShow: function(tip, node) {
                //count connections
                var count = 0;
                node.eachAdjacency(function() { count++; });
                //display node info in tooltip
                tip.innerHTML = "<div class=\"tip-title\">" + node.name + "</div>"
                  + "<div class=\"tip-text\"><b>connections:</b> " + count + "</div>";
              }
            },
            // Add node events
            Events: {
              enable: true,
              type: 'Native',
              //Change cursor style when hovering a node
              onMouseEnter: function() {
                fd.canvas.getElement().style.cursor = 'move';
              },
              onMouseLeave: function() {
                fd.canvas.getElement().style.cursor = '';
              },
              //Update node positions when dragged
              onDragMove: function(node, eventInfo, e) {
                  var pos = eventInfo.getPos();
                  node.pos.setc(pos.x, pos.y);
                  fd.plot();
              },
              //Implement the same handler for touchscreens
              onTouchMove: function(node, eventInfo, e) {
                $jit.util.event.stop(e); //stop default touchmove event
                this.onDragMove(node, eventInfo, e);
              },
              //Add also a click handler to nodes
              onClick: function(node) {
                if(!node) return;
                // Build the right column relations list.
                // This is done by traversing the clicked node connections.
                var html = "<h4>" + node.name + "</h4><b> connections:</b><ul><li>",
                    list = [];
                node.eachAdjacency(function(adj){
                  list.push(adj.nodeTo.name);
                });
                //append connections information
                $jit.id('inner-details').innerHTML = html + list.join("</li><li>") + "</li></ul>";
              }
            },
            //Number of iterations for the FD algorithm
            iterations: 200,
            //Edge length
            levelDistance: 130,
            // Add text to the labels. This method is only triggered
            // on label creation and only for DOM labels (not native canvas ones).
            onCreateLabel: function(domElement, node){
              domElement.innerHTML = node.name;
              var style = domElement.style;
              style.fontSize = "0.8em";
              style.color = "#ddd";
            },
            // Change node styles when DOM labels are placed
            // or moved.
            onPlaceLabel: function(domElement, node){
              var style = domElement.style;
              var left = parseInt(style.left);
              var top = parseInt(style.top);
              var w = domElement.offsetWidth;
              style.left = (left - w / 2) + 'px';
              style.top = (top + 10) + 'px';
              style.display = '';
            }
          });
          // load JSON data.
          fd.loadJSON(json);
          // compute positions incrementally and animate.
          fd.computeIncremental({
            iter: 40,
            property: 'end',
            onStep: function(perc){
              Log.write(perc + '% loaded...');
            },
            onComplete: function(){
              Log.write('done');
              fd.animate({
                modes: ['linear'],
                transition: $jit.Trans.Elastic.easeOut,
                duration: 2500
              });
            }
          });
          // end
        }
    </script>
    {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>{{ topic.title }}</h1>
    </div>  
    <h2>Схема</h2>
        <div id="graph"></div>
    <h2>Высказывания</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for argelement in arg_elements %}
            <li>{{ argelement.contents }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>


    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be object `Log` does exception? Try add `<div id='log'></div>` to page or cut `Log` from page.

Are there  exceptions at the console?

Comment: Nope, there aren't any exceptions and if I add the `log` div, the graph is laid out. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you need to add a div "Log" in your html part or eliminate log from your script.

Apart from that, the div "infovis" in which the graph is rendered (which in your case is "graph"), is given certain styles in the example that you are referring to, which is as follows....

```
#infovis {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also, this div is in another div called "center-container" which is given following styles.

```
#center-container {
  width:600px;
  left:200px;
  background-color:#1a1a1a;
  color:#ccc;
}
```

Basically, the div which you use to render the graph should have enough height and width so that the graph rendered can be seen clearly. If height and width are not given then graph won't be seen even if it is rendered. You may want to apply proper background color as well.

All these styles are in the file base.css which the example includes. You can refer to it at

```
Jit\Examples\css
```